# Особенности возврата результата reverse из функции в Perl

Tags: perl

Для предисловия делаем тестовый код, который переводит строку в верхний регистр, немного комбинируя способы вызова и возврата из функций:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$str="Abc";
$s1=a($str);  $s2=b(a($str));  $s3=c($str);  $s4=b(c($str));
print "str=$str;  a()=$s1; b(a())=$s2; c()=$s3; b(c())=$s4\n";

sub b {  return $_[0];  }
sub a {  my($tmp)=$_[0];  return uc($tmp); }
sub c {  my($tmp)=$_[0];  return $tmp=uc($tmp);  }
```

Результат работы абсолютно предсказуемый:

> str=abc;  a()=ABC; b(a())=ABC; c()=ABC; b(c())=ABC

А теперь абсолютно то же самое сделаем, что бы развернуть строку задом наперед, используя функцию `reverse` вместо `uc`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$str="Abc";
$s1=a($str);  $s2=b(a($str));  $s3=c($str);  $s4=b(c($str));
print "str=$str;  a()=$s1; b(a())=$s2; c()=$s3; b(c())=$s4\n";

sub b { return $_[0]; }
sub a { my($tmp)=$_[0]; return reverse($tmp); }
sub c { my($tmp)=$_[0]; return $tmp=reverse($tmp); }
```

И тут мы получаем абсолютно неожиданный результат:

> str=Abc;  a()=cbA; b(a())=**Abc**; c()=cbA; b(c())=cbA

При передаче результата работы функции `a`, как параметра, в функцию `b` (которая просто возвращает полученное значение) на выходе мы получаем не перевернутую строку. При этом, практически идентичная функция `c` ведет себя так, как и было задумано. Собственно вот это присваивание `$tmp=reverse($tmp)` при `return` я придумал, когда боролся с неожиданным поведением с возвратом после `reverse`. Когда первый раз увидел это, ставил печать в функцию `b`, у нее на входе именно такое значение как она и возвращает и которое собственно напечатано в результате.

**UPD:** Проверил `print b(reverse($str));` возвращает `Abc` !!!

Добавлю, что такой результат на Perl v5.12.4, на других версиях не проверял.

**Вопрос:** почему при возврате значения которое вернула `reverse` в случае прямого его использования поведение ожидаемое, а при передаче этого значения как параметра в другую функцию результат такой, как будто никакого `reverse` не было выполнено ? Глюк это или фича ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Результат абсолютно ожидаемый и предсказуемый. Функция reverse работает по разному в скалярном и списочном контексте. В списочном контексте она разворачивает список, в скалярном - строку.

А теперь вопрос. Если у нас есть список с одной строки, то что вернет для него reverse? Естественно, саму строку.

При вызове `b(a())` перл пытается понять контекст. Функция b возвращает просто свой первый аргумент, а получает на вход - список (она же функция, а аргументы у нее не были специфицированы). Поэтому, функция a должна возвращать список. Отсюда, return возвращает список. А это значит, что контест списочный. В списочном контексте аргумент считается списком и естественно строка стает списком с одним элементом.

В функции c подобного не происходит - там явно виден скалярный контекст.

P.S. код ужасен. Не пишите так. Как минимум используйте `use strict; use warnings` и `my`.

Comment: Т.е. определить свое поведение она может только по контексту, по параметрам это сделать походу невозможно ... А как функции `a` сказать возвращать список ? P.S. А я так обычно и не пишу. Это тестовый код из которого максимально убран весь лишний текст, не относящийся к вопросу

Comment: хотите список - используйте список, или babycart `@{[...]}` - `return @{[reverse $str]}`. Либо явно возвращайте список (например, через массив). Только в этом случае вывод Вас снова порадует:)

P.S. Вы слишком много убрали:)